# font-weight doesn't work on option of select in browser except firefox

Tags: html, html-select

http://jsfiddle.net/GFVAB

HTML code:

```html
<select>
    <option>first</option>
    <option class="light">second</option>
    <option class="bold">third bold</option>
</select>
```

css:

```css
.bold{font-weight:bold !important;}
.light{font-weight:light !important;}
```

There is my example, what I want (it works in Firefox). Any ideas?

Comment: Formatting for certain controls that are rendered by the OS mainly and not by the browser is limited, depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to use a custom select replacement, e.g. ddSlick?http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

Comment: I can't use replacement :) Probably I use <optiongroup> but it doesn't solve my task.

Comment: I tried this, but with optiongroups you have the same problem in chrome

Comment: Looks like your snippet is supported now in Chrome, IE11 and Edge.